# Downloads consistently kill themselves after 1-3 minutes (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-11, download, internet-connection, desktop-computer

For several months now, I have been nearly unable to download most things larger than 100MB, because before the download completes, the download speed drops to 0 and never picks back up again. At the moment I have a download manager, but that only works for direct downloads, not programs that prefer to download things themselves. I have a handful of other network related issues that I think may be related, so rather than work around this issue, I'd like to understand and solve it.

I am running a Windows 11 PC on an ethernet connection. I have tried WiFi to no success. I suspect at least one other computer on my network suffers the same problem, but it has been hard to verify* (as it downloads way faster than mine). My modem has been reset multiple times to no effect. I have a lot of trouble trying to troubleshoot this problem via the internet as I am unable to effectively find anyone describing my issue (most likely due to my poor searching skills). I legitimately do not know how to troubleshoot my problem.

EDIT: No I can calrify, it definitely effects other PCs on the same network.

Comment: If it affects also other PCs, it can be either the cables (no because you tried wifi), routers or the box. If not, then it can come from the ISP. Do at least SOME PCs have no problem? What's their difference?

Comment: @Sylvain There are 2 PCs that I cannot test right now, one of which I may be able to test at a later time. I just tested a laptop and got the same result. I've used ethernet and a WiFi adapter on mine, the other PC has built in WiFi, so I'm unsure if any of those are the cause. If the problem is with router, box, or ISP how do I properly troubleshoot it so I can understand it and either fix it or properly ask for help from my ISP provider?

Comment: The VERY first step is to see if 1 or more is working normally. If so, it's probably not your ISP fault. Even if it is, good luck with this ;-) But yes, you've got to find out the differences between other PCs that work (if any) and don't. That's base of troubleshooting. Like which system, version, browser... It can be a Sherlock Holmes process. @Thomas Wood

Comment: I appreciate the help and will branch out to another PC. I do however highly suspect the problem is at least as far back as the modem/router, since this effects 3 very different computers, effects downloads on all sort of platforms and programs, and causes other similar-but-not-quite-download-related issues.

Comment: Yes. Say it's the modem, box, router. Then what, why does it works for those ones and not these ones? Maybe Win10 and Win11 or Win7? A switch? Cables? Knowing the differences will help you to diagnostic. While this, and if you can, try this: put your phone in wifi access point, connect your computer to this wifi, and see if now the computer can download normally. That may help. The idea of diagnostic is to eliminate factors. If the said computer can download normally in wifi on your phone, then the computer works fine. @Thomas Wood

Comment: Unsurprisingly, it's way slower to download, but on the bright side (if you can call it that) the download stays at ~250Kb/s concsistently, instead of dropping to 0 a minute in. This only adds to my suspicion that the problem is modem/router/box related and I still am not expereinced enough to know what to do next or what to replace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143099/discussion-between-sylvain-and-thomas-wood).